# Depoyment of pre-built Azure Web Service via PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell, azure

I am completely new to Azure and PowerShell but have been tasked with setting up a build and deploy solution for several app services.

We currently have a build server (Azure VM) that is running CruiseControl.NET to build and test some C# .NET solutions that should be deployed in Azure.

This build server currently handles the following tasks:

- Pulling code from source control when commits happen
- Building the projects
- Running some unit test cases
- Copying output/binaries to an output location

However, as it exists now, developers of each of our app services need to 'Publish' their services manually from their development machines by clicking the button in Visual Studio once they have verified that the build and test cases have passed in the test environment on the server.

As I am hoping for a completely automated solution, I expect I need to use something like PowerShell or the Azure Cross Platform CLI (npm) to do this?

I'm extremely confused with the Azure Service Management vs Azure Resource Management versions with the new Azure Powershell 1.0. All of our services appear to be the newer Resource Management versions, not 'classic'.

The eventual goal is to have the build server do the following

- Pulling code from source control when commits happen
- Building the projects
- Running some unit test cases
- Copying output/binaries to an output location
- If the build and test cases are successful, update the service in azure to the latest build

I am hoping there is a way to set up these projects, or take the existing binaries that result from the builds, and have them be deployed into Web Apps using the new Azure Resource Management Powershell features.

Any advice or resources for more information about how this can be done?

Hopefully this makes some sense. Please let me know if I am going about this completely the wrong way or direct me to a more correct forum.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you consider to use Azure App Service? where you can get those build infrastructure for free. e.g https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/

Once you setup continues deployment, you will get below three when there is push event (if you are using git)

- Pulling code from source control when commits happen
- Building the projects
- Copying output/binaries to an output location

and to "Running some unit test cases", you can create your own batch or powershell script with post deployment hook https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Post-Deployment-Action-Hooks

Comment: Yeah, this is almost exactly the solution I was planning to use initially! The requirement of CruiseControl.NET to handle the builds and provide a nice web front end made it so I could no longer use the built in Azure continuous deployment features.